# Searching for strings withing a string

Tags: string, search

I have a large number of strings (potentially 1,000,000+), and I want to search another string (a document) to see which of these search strings appears in the document.

Not all of the search strings are a single word, so it's not just a case of searching for each word in the document in the list of search strings.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

I will be doing this for a large number of documents (coming from a feed), and need to do it fast enough that I can process the documents quicker than they're coming in (a second or two at most ideally).

I can potentially come up with a list of stop words that won't appear in the search strings (e.g. 'the', 'and').

Ideally the solution will be in Java, but that's not a requirement as I can always port the code into Java. If it makes any difference, the search strings are currently stored in a MongoDB.

Comment: Please tag with a language; or you might get a solution in FORTRAN77 without while.

Comment: How big is the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Radix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) and [Suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

There is an example on the [concurrent-trees](http://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees/) project, of how to scan unseen documents efficiently for large numbers of keywords stored in the inverted radix tree in that project. Example code [here](http://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees/wiki/ConcurrentInvertedRadixTreeUsage).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [High-perfor­mance pattern matching algo­rithms Java](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/)